# How to get absolute position of any component in any layout Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, point, autocompletetextview

Maybe this is a stupid question but I lose hours trying it. I have any JFrame with her components inside. This JFrame can have any Layout. My question is simple
I have this window: In the image I use absolute layout to know the real location.

[image]

I want know the position of the button. I'm using a GridBagLayout and when I do button.getY() or button.getX() , I have 0 ever, in X or Y. But if I use absolute layout, I have not problem.

If I use absoluteLayout I know that I have not this problem. But I want use any layout and  know the absolute position of any component in the frame.

Really I want to do a autocomplete textField ( like google when you are writing to search ), when I write in the TextField , I want show other window jframe below textfield with the coincidences.

If I know the absolute position of any textfiel, I can calculate the position and show the new window.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the [`SwingUtilities.convertPoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29) methods should do what you want. The following example prints `java.awt.Point[x=54,y=22]`.

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new JLabel("Test"), BorderLayout.WEST);
JButton b = new JButton("Test");
f.add(b);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(b, b.getX(), b.getY(), f));
```

Comment: Don't forget about `SwingUtilities.convertRectangle()`